# Acumulacion de peticiones ajax en evento onclick jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy desarrollando un sistema web con PHP / mysql / jquery para una sala de juegos la cual debe registrar en BD la hora de inicio de cada mesa (dando click en un div). Hasta ese punto todo bien.

Cuando el juego termina, para cortar el tiempo y hacer el calculo del cobro se tiene que dar click al mismo div, la cual abre una ventana modal que contiene un pequeño formulario que envia info mediante ajax a PHP y luego a la base de datos.

El problema viene cuando se finalizan varios juegos en la misma mesa (sin actualizar la pagina): se ejecuta la peticion ajax (con un solo click) la misma cantidad de veces que se han finalizado los juegos anteriores. O sea que si anteriormente se han finalizado el juego 3 veces en en la misma mesa, la solicitud ajax para enviar los datos a php se ejecuta 3 veces y cada una de esta peticion contiene los mismos parametros que en su momento tuvo.

```
//esta es la captura del evento onclick con jquery
$('.modal_mesas').on('show.bs.modal' , function(){
        var modal_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var indice = modal_id.indexOf('_');
        var id = modal_id.substring(indice + 1);        

        $("#pagado_"+id).on("click", function(){              
            llama_accion_php("session", "registra_tiempo", id, "fin");
            return false;
        });
    });`
```

```
// la peticion ajax
function llama_accion_php(seccion, accion, id, funcion){
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "./index_ajax.php?seccion="+seccion+"&accion="+accion,
      data:{mesa: id, funcion: funcion},
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){

      },
      error: function(xhr, status){

      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hola Javier, bienvenido. Creo que está claro el comportamiento que posee tu programa actualmente. Podrías ampliar la pregunta, indicando cual es el comportamiento que necesitas o esperas que tenga tu código?

Comment: Lo unico que deseo es que por cada click sea solo una peticion y no se acumulen

Comment: al parecer estas casando el event varias veces, necesitas sacar $('.modal_mesas').on('show.bs.modal' , function() de tu evento click

Comment: es correcto, o estoy cazando varias veces porque funcionamiento asi lo requiere (iniciar y terminar los tiempos del juego). Ya intente sacar la captura de ese evento fuera del modal pero se comporta de la misma manera.

Answer (score 0):

Les comento que ya lo resolví y espero que a alguien mas le sirva.

Lo que hice fue eliminar el evento click a ese boton para "liberar la cache" y despues darselo nuevamente.

```
$('.modal_mesas').on('show.bs.modal' , function(){
        var modal_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var indice = modal_id.indexOf('_');
        var id = modal_id.substring(indice + 1);

        $("#pagado_"+id).off('click');
        $("#pagado_"+id).click(function(e){  
            e.preventDefault();
            llama_accion_php(id, "fin");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que otra forma de resolver el problema es usando el evento one
$("#elemento").one("click", function(){}